# Response object in Rspec 1.3.4 with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to use the following test to see if a login form correctly redirects:

```
    it "should allow you to login" do
    visit "/"
    fill_in 'Email', :with => 'admin@example.com'
    fill_in 'Pass', :with => 'password'
    click_button 'Login'
    response.should be_redirect
end
```

However, rspec fails with the message that response doesn't exist. I'm running a rails 2.3.4 app, so I have rspec 1.3.4 installed. How do I test for the response?

Comment: my tip in situations like this is to use the Pry gem, and place binding.pry right before the response line. You can then inspect the Capybara objects like this, page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an integration spec (what RSpec calls a 'request spec' in version 2)? If so, the response object is not available. For that, you'll need a controller spec, e.g.:

```
describe MyController do
  it "should redirect" do
    post :some_path, {:email => 'admin@example.com', :pass => 'password'}
    response.should be_redirect
  end
end
```

Or in your integration spec, test the expected path after a successful redirect. This works in RSpec 2, not sure about RSpec 1:

```
current_path.should == "/some_path"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ask Capybara instead of the rails test helpers.

```
session.status_code.should == "301"  # or 302
```

should do it.

Look at the examples here:

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#status_code-instance_method